# How to display image over image on hover with css

Tags: css, image, hover

I have a gallery of images with [links](http://costumingdiary.blogspot.com/p/costume-pattern-reviews.html).

Edit: Here's the code I have to work with:

```
<div class="gallerypagetabs"><a href="http://costumingdiary.blogspot.com/2013/01/victorian-tardis-purse.html"><img alt="Free Victorian Purse Pattern" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-m4y6eS2KGRQ/Ug7TKD3sbYI/AAAAAAAAHNc/6qoeuGedjOY/s200-c/free-victorian-purse-pattern-1.jpg"><br>Free Victorian Purse Pattern</a><a href="http://costumingdiary.blogspot.com/2012/12/natural-form-victorian-overskirt.html"><img alt="Natural Form Victorian Overskirt" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ZrTDaXEOiiU/US__mPzz3dI/AAAAAAAADWQ/eBm3tO3P8oI/s200-c/IMG_5482%255B6%255D.jpg"><br>Natural Form Victorian Overskirt</a><a href="http://costumingdiary.blogspot.com/2012/11/truly-victorian-tv221-1878-tie-back.html"><img alt="Truly Victorian TV221 1878 Underskirt Pattern Review" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-GmrRTxJ5NGY/UKfO_SQzymI/AAAAAAAAAHA/A9qx6czpyJk/s200-c/Truly-Victorian-TV221-1878-Tie-Back-%255B1%255D%255B4%255D.png"><br>Truly Victorian TV221 1878 Underskirt Pattern Review</a><a href="http://costumingdiary.blogspot.com/2012/10/truly-victorian-tv121-petticoat-pattern.html"><img alt="Truly Victorian TV121 Petticoat Pattern Review" src="http://lh4.ggpht.com/-qTsclIxCTKY/UH7fK3jqKII/AAAAAAAAodI/2GaQOVrGuuA/s200-c/Truly%252520Victorian%252520TV121%2525201879%252520Petticoat%252520with%252520Detachable%252520Train%25255B6%25255D.png?imgmax=800"><br>Truly Victorian TV121 Petticoat Pattern Review</a>..ad naseum..</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallerypagetabs a,.gallerypagetabs p{
    float:left;
    font-size:.80em;
    height:250px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align: center;
    width:200px
}
```

What I'd like to do is show a transparent image with stars on them when someone hovers over the image. So if a person hovers over the Free Victorian Purse Pattern image, they'll see an image of - let's say - five stars indicating that the pattern has received a rating of 5 out of 5 stars from me.

I've tried both of the following with no luck. The code shows the image on hover, but it shows at the bottom of the image instead of overlapping it:

```
.gallerypagetabs a:hover{
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/IKAXZKz.png');
    background-position:inherit
 }
```

AND

```
.gallerypagetabs a:hover{
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/IKAXZKz.png');
    background-position:inherit;
    z-index:10
}
```

Any advice? I don't want to use Javascript, and I <strike>want to add as little coding to the HTML as possible</strike> cannot change the html other than adding another class or id at the beginning of it. It all has to be done through CSS. Here's how I'd like it to look. Thanks for your help!

[image]

The code that WORKS! (Thanks cimmanon!)
(Changed gallerypagetabs to gallerypatterntab to isolate the class from the rest of the blog. Screenshot from Blogger - yeah Blogger likes to rewrite things like quotations)
[image]

Comment: I think the issue is your link is actually behind the image, so it might be applying the hover effect, but you don't see it because your `<img>` is in front.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a pseudo element for this purpose.  No need for extra markup.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/anxnrkhr

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" /></a>

a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5); /* your background */
  width: 20px; /* image width */
  height: 100px; /* image height */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Is the # replacing the link? I don't want to do that.

Comment: It's just example markup to show that your existing markup will work just fine (though you may want to add a class somewhere).

Comment: IT WORKS! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

.gallerypagetabs a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.gallerypagetabs a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/IKAXZKz.png'); /* your background */
  width: 200px; /* image width */
  height: 200px; /* image height */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

Comment: For posterity, I had to isolate that class from the rest of the blog, so I changed the class to gallerypatterntab for that page only.

Comment: You don't want to comment out the width/height properties:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/84cu2cvw.

Comment: Yes, the closing tags */ are in the css in the proper place (as in the original code) and working perfectly. *happydance*

I copied/pasted the css code (closing tags and all) from my Blogger template to here. Weird that the tags rewrote themselves when I posted it. O.o I blame Blogger. :) I'm going to edit my original post to add a screenshot of my final working code.

Comment: OMG, this system did it again! I'm 100% sure I typed the asterisk before the slash, and after the happydance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Putting the image on the *anchor's background* isn't going to work because the image will hide it.

You can add an element containing the stars in an [absolute position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) inside the *anchor*:

```
<a href="http://costumingdiary.blogspot.com/2013/01/victorian-tardis-purse.html">
    <img src="https://lh3.goog...An-purse-pattern-1.jpg" alt="Free.. Pattern">
    <br>
    Free Victorian Purse Pattern
    <i class="stars"></i>
</a>
```

And a CSS similar to this (all numbers can vary):

```
a { 
    position: relative;
}

.stars {
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/IKAXZKz.png');
    background-position:inherit;
    width: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    display: none;
}

a:hover .stars {
    display: block;
}
```

---

P.S - `<br />` is supposed to be self-closing. And it's better not using it only to make a new line after the image, but maybe give the image this style:

```
a img { 
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work either. Actually, something like this won't work for me anyway, because I use Blogger label pages to create my html for my static page.

In other words, I click on this page:
http://costumingdiary.blogspot.com/search/label/Patterns?max-results=500

then copy/paste in to the static page:
http://costumingdiary.blogspot.com/p/costume-pattern-reviews.html

It makes it easy for me to update the static page, because Google refuses to crawl Blogger label pages.

The label page is riddled in javascript (that I didn't write) which creates the page.

Comment: The <br /> is created by either Blogger or the javascript. I'd get rid of it too if I could. Blogger LOVES to add <br /> everywhere. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I think you want something like:

```
.gallerypagetabs a, .gallerypagetabs img{
     position:absolute;
     z-index:1;
 }

 .gallerypagetabs a:hover{
     z-index:2;
 }

 .gallerypagetabs{
     position:relative;
 }
```

This is untested, but hopefully gives you an idea about how to realize the effect you are after.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the z-index. With the above, your links with the stars will, on hover, have a higher z-index than the `<img>` and should be placed higher on the visibility stack.

Comment: Why the downvote? This will show the stars in the link on hover. Please let me know how I have misunderstood this.

Comment: The image is inside the anchor.

Comment: Tried adding the above z-index, but it didn't work. It just squished everything together. Actually, that was the first thing I thought of after you told me the link was behind the image. Let me try the next code...