# show link over the image when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to archive effect like in [this site](http://www.canstockphoto.com/images-photos/hacker.html)

when I hover over the image I want to show a link with bootstrap icon. I am using bootstrap 3.

```
original image
```

[image]

```
when hovered
```

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please share some code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using just html and css.

HTML:

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/240/310" />
    <a class="show-on-hover" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.img-wrap img {
    display: block;
}

.show-on-hover {
    display: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 0;
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/20/30');
}

.img-wrap:hover .show-on-hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HRb4L/

Answer (score 5):

**CSS**

```
.main-block {
width:200px;
height:auto;
position:relative;
display:block;}

.main-block img{width:100%; }

.main-block .badge {width:29px;
height:55px;
background:url(images/badge.png) no-repeat 0 0;
position:absolute;
right:10px;
top:0;
display:none;}

.main-block .badge a {display:block;
height:55px;}

.main-block:hover .badge {display:block;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-block"><div class="badge"><a href="#"></a></div><img src="images/character-render.gif" width="400" height="300" alt="1" /> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using CSS

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#"><img src="img_url" /></a>
```

**CSS**:

```
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5); /* your background */
  width: 20px; /* image width */
  height: 100px; /* image height */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361924/how-to-display-image-over-image-on-hover-with-css#18362993)

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient way, but yes, you can achieve it with something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail-parent">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  <div class="badge"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail-parent, .thumbnail {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.badge {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: Black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.thumbnail-parent:hover .badge {
    visibility: visible;

}
```