# 'Hover image display image' CSS is not working properly

Tags: html, css, image, hover, display

I searched around the Internet and found this: [How to display image over image on hover with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361924/how-to-display-image-over-image-on-hover-with-css).
I tried the code of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOjXI.png) in jsfiddle and blog article using Chrome and Firefox.
None of them shows result like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RslYz.jpg).
What is not correct in my code? Thanks.

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/fGAbTOj.png');
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/271590/ss_80b965d66b13d6eb5e1468151a371e12fe159663.600x338.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `background-size` property, as you are setting a `background-image` property to `a:before` element and the size of the background image is `256x256`. But you've defined the `width` & `height` of the `a:before` element to `50px`, so the size of the background image should also be `50px`.

Just use:

```
a:hover:before {
  background-size: 50px; /* as you have 'width' and 'height' defined as 50px each */
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/fGAbTOj.png');
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/271590/ss_80b965d66b13d6eb5e1468151a371e12fe159663.600x338.jpg" /></a>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it only works with `background-size`. But I still have a question that why the code of that image still works even `background-size` is missing.

Comment: @ll55 Its my pleasure! But I still didn't understand, what code is working when the `background-size` is missing, maybe I didn't get your question.

Comment: The code in `https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOjXI.png` can display image when hovering image even `background-size` is missing.

Comment: @ll55 Its because your you've given `width: 200px` and `height: 200px` to your `:before` element, and the background image's actual width & height is around `200px`, so its visible there. But in the current scenario you've assigned the `:before` element a width & height of `50px`, but the actual image size is `256 x 256`. So its not visible as it has only `50 x 50` to show the image size. In my answer I am resizing the background-image to `:before` element width & height i.e., `50 x 50`. Hope it helps!